# Issue trying to publish my current project

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have an issue trying to publish my customization project in the Customization Project Editor. The compilation panel remains completely in blank and I don't get any information.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the instance?

Comment: Yes, I already did that before, I even restarted the IIS service but everything remains the same, all my instances are like this.

Comment: I had the same issue this morning.  Try going back to the Customization Projects screen (not into the project) and publish from there.  It worked for me, and then I was able to go back to publishing from inside the actual customization project.

Comment: In fact, that's what I've been doing but I have not been able to publish from inside the current customization project, @BrianStevens

Comment: I just had this issue a minute ago.  Never before though.  What's up with that?

Comment: I still don't know why that happens, for the moment I'm publishing the projects in Customization Projects screen. @Deetz

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado Same.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by .NET version 4.8.4250. Workaround is to add the following key to appSettings section of your web.config.

```
<add key="aspnet:DisableAppPathModifier" value="false" />
```